# Equivalent of pausing (CTRL-Z bindkey) in shell-mode

Tags: shell-mode

Let's say that I run a process in the foreground, I then wish to pause it, and maybe assign it to the background. In normal C-shell, it is very easily done. I just press `C-z`, and then I input the command `bg &`. How can I achieve the same in emacs shell-mode?

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-z</kbd>, which runs `comint-stop-subjob`, is the `shell-mode` equivalent.

Use <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> from your shell buffer to see other bindings on that prefix which may be of interest.

Comment: This should be marked as the right question. Take my vote up, @phils.